# LogicApp - how to use length to check if collection is empty

Tags: azure-logic-apps

In my JSON results, I'm trying to see if a particular object exists, and if it does exist, what is the count. I'm using `length` expression but it seems to be failing for me with error:

```
The template function 'lenth' is not defined or not valid.
```

Here is my `Get_Ticket` object:

```
{
    "TicketInfo": {
        "key1": "val1",
        "key2": "val2",
        "key3": "val3"
    },
    "TicketEquipmentInfo": [{
        "EquipKey1": "val1",
        "EquipKey2": "val2"
    }, {
        "EquipKey1": "val3",
        "EquipKey2": "val3"
    }]
}
```

Here is my expression:

```
if(contains(body('Get_Ticket'), 'TicketEquipmentInfo'), if(greater(lenth(body('Get_Ticket')['TicketEquipmentInfo']), 0), 'Found at least 1 piece of Equipment', '<leave blank, empty array found>'), '<leave blank, no array found>')
```

What am I doing wrong? Also open to suggestions to make this expression more efficient without having to modify the logic app design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a typo - use not lenth but **length**.

Comment: Ran into same kind of issue. In my case it was lenght - not sure how compiler allows this in the first place